# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'demooabgov_root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `roles`) unsolved

Tags: php, laravel

This error is occurring frequently. Last time I tried `php artisan config:cache` and It worked on C-Panel. This time not working. All tried  `php artisan optimize` `composer update` and so on. Double checked Database and User / Password. All are correct. But still got error.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'demooabgov_root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `roles`)

Laravel 8 php 7.3

Comment: is the information on your .env correct? Is your database service running?

Comment: 1) Try to check and fix your db table in MySQL
2) Try to check settings for your password and host, like is it localhost, all, or smth else

Comment: Yes .env is correct and I Checked all possible soln found on stackoverflow and google but not solved till.

Comment: Yes .env is correct and I Checked all possible soln found on stackoverflow and google but not solved till.  @IGP

Comment: Password is correct like spelling correct and others points are correct

Comment: Are you able to access the database directly from the command line? Does the problem persist if you change localhost by 127.0.0.1 ?